# Conditional Expectation on Bernoulli Variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

From Basic Probability Theory by Ash:

Let $R$ be the number of successes in $n$ Bernoulli trials, with probability $p$ of success on a given trial. Find the conditional expectation of $R$ given that $R \geq 2$.

My thoughts:
We know that the probability that the number of success is greater than 2 is 
$ \Sigma_{i=2}^{n} \binom{n}{i} p^i \cdot p^{n-i}$. Then the probability of each event occurring $(k=2,3,4)$ = $\binom{n}{k} p^k \cdot p^{n-k}$. So for each event we say the conditional expectation is $\frac{k \cdot \binom{n}{k} p^k \cdot p^{n-k}}{\Sigma_{i=2}^{n} \binom{n}{i} p^i \cdot p^{n-i}}$, so then the total probability will be 
$$\Sigma_{k=2}^{n} \left [\frac{k \cdot \binom{n}{k} p^k \cdot p^{n-k}}{\Sigma_{i=2}^{n} \binom{n}{i} p^i \cdot p^{n-i}} \right]$$

Something feels kind of murky about this, and when I write it out I always get strange answers.

Comment: You should really show more of your work, including what attempt you have made.

Comment: my apologies I will edit the question

Comment: What you have is good so far.  See the answer below for further hints in simplifying the sums in the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have tried so far is correct.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(R\mid R\geq 2) & = \sum_{k=0}^n k\; \mathsf P(R=k\mid R\geq 2)
\\[2ex] & = \frac{\sum\limits_{k=\color{blue}{2}}^n k\;\mathsf P(R=k)}{\mathsf P(R\geq 2)}
\\[2ex] & = \frac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} k\; p^k\;(1-p)^{n-k}}{\sum\limits_{j=2}^n \binom{n}{j}\;p^j\;(1-p)^{n-j}} & \color{green}{\checkmark}
\end{align}$$

Now consider though that: $$\mathsf P(R\geq 2)=1-\mathsf P(R<2)$$

Consider also that: $$\sum\limits_{k=\color{blue}{0}}^n k\; \mathsf P(R=k) = np$$

---

**Another method**  By the Law of Iterated Expectation:  $$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(R) & = \mathsf E(R\mid R<2)\mathsf P(R< 2) + \mathsf E(R\mid R\geq 2)\mathsf P(R\geq 2)
\\[2ex] \therefore \mathsf E(R\mid R\geq 2) &= \dfrac{\mathsf E(R)-\mathsf E(R\mid R<2)\mathsf P(R< 2)}{\mathsf P(R\geq 2)}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\mathsf E(R) - \sum_{k=0}^1 k\;\mathsf P(R=k\mid R<2)\mathsf P(R<2)}{1-\mathsf P(R<2)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up for me.